# How to Separate 4 numbers in 2 parts in C language

Tags: arrays, c, math, get, numbers

I want to get 4 numbers from user like 1234(printf("enter 4 numbers: "); and separate them like 12 and 34
the out put I mean :

year : 12

month : 34

Comment: Try [`div()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/div.html)?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? How do you read your input? Do you read a string? A number? Edit your question to include the code you have so far.

Comment: If you read an integer, try `/` and `%`.

Answer (score 0):

You did not explain what you can read from users very clearly. Say you get the input from the following code:

```
int a;
scanf("%d", &a);
```

and you are very sure that the input is definitely a 4-digit integer. You can do:

```
int a1 = a / 100;
int a2 = a % 100;
printf("%d, %d", a1, a2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below operations yeilds the result that are expected.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num, year, month;
    scanf("%d",&num);
    year = num%100;
    month = num/100;
    printf("month : %d\t",year);
    printf(" year: %d",month);
}
```

[image]